# Time between client inputs in socket communication

Tags: java

I have a simple socket server client communication in java where the clinet introduce a string and the server return the number of spaces from that string. I want to finish the communication if the client does'n introduce nothing for more than 10 seconds but i don't know how. Any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

[setSoTimeout(10000)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29)

Comment: I don't think OP wants the socket to close after 10 seconds, he just only wants to start processing the input after 10 seconds.

Comment: @glowcoder, this is a very correct answer for blocking IO and the OP would have not asked anything if any idea of non-blocking processing has sprung into the mind.